# Not able to fetch data from the second table on join query in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I was trying to fetch a category list using left join (on the same table) to get the parent category as well.

The query looks like

```
SELECT categories.`cat_id`, categories.`cat_name`, categories.`cat_desc`, categories.`parent_id`, categories.`created_at`,cat2.cat_name FROM `categories` JOIN categories cat2 ON categories.parent_id = cat2.cat_id
```

So on Laravel eloquent i wrote

```
$categoryModel::select('categories.cat_id', 'categories.cat_name', 'categories.cat_desc', 'categories.parent_id', 'categories.created_at','cat2.cat_name')
    ->leftJoin('categories AS cat2','categories.parent_id', '=' , 'cat2.cat_id')
    ->get();
```

Unfortunately, the result comes with only the first table columns

`[{"cat_id":1,"cat_name":"Camera","cat_desc":null,"parent_id":3,"created_at":null},{"cat_id":2,"cat_name":"Camera","cat_desc":null,"parent_id":3,"created_at":null},{"cat_id":3,"cat_name":null,"cat_desc":null,"parent_id":null,"created_at":null},{"cat_id":4,"cat_name":null,"cat_desc":null,"parent_id":null,"created_at":null},{"cat_id":5,"cat_name":"CCTV","cat_desc":null,"parent_id":4,"created_at":null},{"cat_id":6,"cat_name":"CCTV","cat_desc":null,"parent_id":4,"created_at":null}]`

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: what do you get with raw query??

Answer (score 1):

Here both table columns have same name, so you need to use alias for second table's column as of this please below change in your query like `'cat2.cat_name as c_name'`

```
$categoryModel::select('categories.cat_id', 'categories.cat_name', 'categories.cat_desc', 'categories.parent_id', 'categories.created_at','cat2.cat_name as c_name' )
    ->leftJoin('categories AS cat2','categories.parent_id', '=' , 'cat2.cat_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: if it is work,can you up vote and accept the answer ?

Answer (score 1):

It worked this way, I gave the alias for each column.

`$categoryModel::select('cat1.cat_id as catId', 'cat1.cat_name as catName', 'cat1.cat_desc as catDesc', 'cat1.parent_id as parId', 'cat1.created_at as cAt','cat2.cat_name as parCatName')
        ->from('categories as cat1')
        ->leftJoin('categories AS cat2','cat1.parent_id', '=' , 'cat2.cat_id')
        ->get();`